# MOODLE Error reading from database

Tags: php, mysql, moodle, moodle-api, moodle-mobile

I have problem transferring the Moodle e-learning to another server
[image]
the error is not helpful, I have tried changing the file:

> moodle/lib/dml/mysqli_native_moodle_database.php Change
>   @@default_storage_engine to @@storage_engine,

the moodle config.php is configured correctly accordingly to my MySQL server which all still does not work

moodle version: 3.2.1 
mysql version: 5.7.9 php version: 7.0.0, tnx in advance

Comment: MOODLE [How to enable and check PHP error logs](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/PHP_error_logs)

Answer (score 1):

Run PHPInfo(). Does it show that PHP has loaded the MySQL driver?

Can you connect to the database via PhpMyAdmin?

And are the PHP error logging options, like **log_errors**, enabled? The Moodle config.php file also has various debugging settings. Are those enabled? Getting better error messages usually makes resolving problems easier.